# "Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed" in VBA when launched from a Powershell, but work when directly call from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm stuck on this problem. An user will go to holiday and want to automate some actions on his Excel. I've created a very basic Powershell for the Windows Task Scheduler that open a first Excel file, launch a macro and close:

```
$target = "G:\ES\GI\xxxx\xxxxMailer.xlsm" #Where is my file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($target) #Open my file
$objExcel.Run("Callxxxx") #Launch a macro in the target file
$workbook.close($false)
$objExcel.Quit()
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
```

In the macro I have this very simple line (so in VBA this time) for opening an other workbook:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\ES\GI\xxxxx\destinations xxxxxx 2018.xlsm", _
    UpdateLinks:=3, _
    ReadOnly:= False
```

My problem is the following: when I launch the macro directly from the first workbook, the second one open without any problem; but when I try to launch the process from Powershell, I got the error "Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed".

I tried to change all properties from Workbooks.Open, disable macro at StartUp from the destination file, same process work with others files and not this one. I'm short on ideas.

Comment: What user runs the task? Can this user access "G:\ES\GI\xxxx\etc\etc"? I think you don't want the Excel to show when run from Scheduled Task, so: `$objExcel.Visible = $false; 
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false; $objExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false; $objExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = $false`. Why open a workbook for the sole purpose of opening another file that runs a macro? Can't you simply add the macro in a `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` function so it aurorunsin the file "G:\ES\GI\xxxxx\destinations xxxxxx 2018.xlsm" and open that file? (or am i not understanding your question right?)

Comment: Hello Theo, thanks for your advise but unfortunatly access are good... I have same problem on my desk. And "workbooks.opening" is a part of a bigger program... But you give me an idea of workaround with the Private Sub Workbook_Open(), maybe open directly from the task scheduler with a condition on the current time. But that error leave me perplex anyway ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from specific addin in the targetted workbook. The $ObjExcel don't run with them loaded correctly. I finally assign the $ObjModel to the full Excel path containing all addins, and not to a "-New-Object" who's running on separate instance. Everything working fine after that.